# SQL Server : stored procedure to return a set with 3 Items

Tags: sql-server

I need to query some tables in a database and return a set of tables.

I don't want to create a `#TempTable`.

There is a way of doing that without a very complicated procedure?

So, I guess, the return of the Stored Procedure, should be a set with 3 tables:

1. The data queried
2. A boolean informing of any errors (I think it can be always false)
3. The page count TOTAL

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SellerCode int = 569;
DECLARE @Year int = 2020;
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'silva';
DECLARE @Document VARCHAR(100) = null;
DECLARE @GroupCode INT = NULL;
DECLARE @UserId int = null;

DECLARE @Paginate BIT = 1;
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 10;
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 1;

 SET @SQL= '  
    Select 
    Client.Id,
    Client.Document,
    Client.Name,
    Client.Active,
    Client.Email,
    Client.GroupCode,
    Client.UserId,

    Estimate.Paid,
    Estimate.Value,
    Estimate.Year

    from Estimate
    INNER JOIN Client
    ON Estimate.ClientId = Client.ClientId
    INNER JOIN Seller
    ON Client.SellerCode = Seller.SellerCode
    Where Client.SellerCode = ' + Convert(varchar(20),@SellerCode);

If (Not @Nome Is NULL)  
 Begin  
 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Client.Name LIKE ''%' + @Name + '%'''  
 End

If (Not @Document Is NULL)  
 Begin  
 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Estimate.Document = ' + Convert(varchar(100),@Document) 
 End

 If (Not @GroupCode Is NULL)  
 Begin  
 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Client.GroupCode = ' + Convert(varchar(20),@GroupCode)   
 End

 If (Not @Year Is NULL)  
 Begin  
 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Estimate.Year = ' + Convert(varchar(10),@Year)
 End

 If (Not @UserId Is NULL)  
 Begin  
 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND Client.UserId = ' + Convert(varchar(20),@UserId)   
 End  

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

I have this query so far. The filters are working, but the returning is only one table.

Can anyone give me an example of how to do that?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I need to paginate the result as well. This is why I need the Total count of the First query, so the front can deal with it.
I inherited a generic Stored Procedure, which is very complex and needs to be simplified to use elsewhere.

Comment: you can return as many tables as you want. Just write more SELECT statements. (But `A boolean informing of any errors`...this isn't the right way to handle that. SQL has ways of returning error codes from procedures already)

Comment: `The page count TOTAL`...do you mean the number of rows returned by the first query? The client can calculate that, if they need to. But I guess you could return it ready-made, if you really want.

Comment: This is wide open to SQL injection. What happens if @Document = `'; TRUNCATE TABLE Client; -- `?? **You can use parameters as normal with sp_executesql, DO NOT concatenate user parameters together like that** Also, look up [keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: @ADyson I have to return a second table with the total, just like you said. The system is already configured in that way, so I can't change it. And that is my great question, how to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should not resort to dynamic SQL for a Kitchen Sink query, because `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` usually suffices. This compiles all the parameters directly into the query, and is usually efficient, unless compilation time is high.

So we should do this statically:

```sql
DECLARE @SellerCode int = 569;
DECLARE @Year int = 2020;
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'silva';
DECLARE @Document VARCHAR(100) = null;
DECLARE @GroupCode INT = NULL;
DECLARE @UserId int = null;

DECLARE @Paginate BIT = 1;
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 10;
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 1;

Select 
    Client.Id,
    Client.Document,
    Client.Name,
    Client.Active,
    Client.Email,
    Client.GroupCode,
    Client.UserId,

    Estimate.Paid,
    Estimate.Value,
    Estimate.Year

from Estimate
INNER JOIN Client
    ON Estimate.ClientId = Client.ClientId
INNER JOIN Seller
    ON Client.SellerCode = Seller.SellerCode
Where Client.SellerCode = @SellerCode
  AND (@Nome Is NULL OR Client.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')
  AND (@Document Is NULL OR Estimate.Document = @Document)
  AND (@GroupCode Is NULL OR Client.GroupCode = @GroupCode)
  AND (@Year Is NULL OR Estimate.Year = @Year)
  AND (@UserId Is NULL OR Client.UserId = @UserId)

ORDER BY ORDERING_COLUMN_GOES_HERE

OFFSET (CASE WHEN @Paginate = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize END) ROWS
FETCH NEXT (CASE WHEN @Paginate = 0 THEN 1000000000 ELSE @PageSize END) ROWS ONLY

OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

I would advise you to look at whether you actually *need* the row count, as this will be pretty inefficient to keep on calculating.

Bear in mind that row-number pagination can have issues, as whenever a row is inserted or removed, the pages change. You should look into doing keyset-pagination instead.

Comment: The Problem is, I haven't the option of doing it the right way. I need to return two tables, and the second table is Total(with the results without the pagination).

Comment: For that you can just do the same query but put instead `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...` and remove the `OFFSET/FETCH` lines. Leave in `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply compare against null in the where and if not null have your expression evaluated.

```
Select 
 Client.Id,
  ...
 TotalCopunt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)
...
from 
  Estimate
  INNER JOIN Client
   ON Estimate.ClientId = Client.ClientId
  INNER JOIN Seller
   ON Client.SellerCode = Seller.SellerCode
 Where Client.SellerCode = @SellerCode
    AND
    (@Name Is NULL)OR(Client.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')
    AND
    (@GroupCode Is NULL)OR(Client.GroupCode = @GroupCode)
```